# BERT- pythorch- regression task - predicting same score for each instance

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I have implemented bert model for a regression task. trained the model and predict, however, model predicts 0 for each instance.

In a nutshell, task was predicting the positivity/negativity of a scientific article between -1 and 1.

Obviously the problem turns out from train (model does not learn) because validation loss does not decrease as expected. I will share the code of my model and look forward to hearing any suggestions. Please, let me know if you need to see other parts of the code.

Thanks!

```
class CustomSciBERTModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
      super(CustomSciBERTModel, self).__init__()
      self.scibert = AutoModel.from_pretrained('allenai/scibert_scivocab_uncased')
      self.num_labels = 1
      self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(768, 1)

    def forward(self, ids, mask,labels):
      output = self.scibert(
            input_ids=ids, 
            attention_mask=mask)
      


      logits = self.linear_layer(output[1]) 
     

      loss = None
      # while training return loss and while validation/ testing resturn logits
      if labels is not None:
        loss_fct = nn.MSELoss()
        #loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() *************
        loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
        return loss
      else:
        return logits
```

Comment: Training parameters?

Comment: If you haven’t trained your linear layer parameters, this makes sense.